# Избыточность слов «алгоритм, порядок» в фразе

Tags: стилистика

"Алгоритм процессуального порядка возбуждения уголовного дела включает в себя три этапа" — не избыточно ли употребление слов «алгоритм, порядок» в таком контексте?

Answer (score 1):

А нельзя ли просто: "... процессуальный порядок возбуждения уголовного дела включает в себя три этапа..."?

Answer (score 0):

Я бы тоже выбросил слово алгоритм, оставив лишь *"процессуальный порядок"*. 
Хочу заметить, что в вашем предложении после *"три этапа"* надо ставить двоеточие, а не тире.

Comment: После слова ЭТАПА может и точка стоять. Дан отрывок предложения. Понятно, что оно незаконченное.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько понимаю "процессуальный порядок" вполне сложившийся термин. Поэтому не вижу ничего страшного, что у него есть алгоритм. Другое дело, что само слово "алгоритм" тоже термин - и в лругой области. Поэтому я бы его как-то заменил. Тем более, что и по смыслу оно здесь, похоже, не совсем точно подходит. Точно сказать не могу, не будучи специалистом в юридических формулировках.

Но возможно, что здесь речь идёт о предписании:

***Предписания процессуального порядка возбуждения уголовного дела...*** 
Как-то так.